# How to make the properties in the script to work also if a circle is now drawn ?and how to make the rotating about around to rotate around on ellipse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to object for example a Cube and draw a circle around the Cube.
The properties at this part in the script are not affecting if the flag bool variable draw is false.

```
if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
                {
                    CreatePoints();
    
                    prevXRadius = xRadius;
                    prevYRadius = yRadius;
                    prevSegments = segments;
                    prevWidth = width;
                    prevHeight = height;
                }
    
                if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
                {
                    yRadius = xRadius;
    
                    CreatePoints();
                }
```

I didn't check all the properties but when I set draw to false and then check enable true the variable controlBothXradiusYradius it's not controlling both xRadius and yRadius like it does when draw is true.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;

                CreatePoints();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

This script is attached to object that rotatearound a target in this case the Cube with the drawn circle and rotatearound on the circle radius :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float rotatingSpeed;
    public float movingSpeed;
    public Vector3 axis;
    public bool randomHeight;
    public float setRandomHeight = 1;
    public float radius;
    public DrawCircle dc;

    private float lastRadius;
    private bool move = false;
    private float t = 0.0f;
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;
    private float prevHeight;
    private Vector3 radiusPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (dc != null)
        {
            lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
            radius = dc.xRadius;
        }
        else
        {
            lastRadius = radius;
        }
        move = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            if (dc != null)
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.localPosition.x, target.localPosition.y, dc.xRadius);
                radius = dc.xRadius;
            }
            else
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.localPosition.x, target.localPosition.y, radius);
            }
        }

        if (move == false)
        {
            if (target != null)
            {
                transform.RotateAround(target.position, axis, rotatingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (randomHeight)
            {
                t += Time.deltaTime;

                if (t > delay)
                {
                    prevHeight = setRandomHeight;
                    setRandomHeight = Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
                    t = 0;
                }

                var tt = transform.position;
                tt.y = Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, setRandomHeight, t);
                transform.position = tt;
            }
        }

        if (dc != null)
        {
            if (lastRadius != dc.xRadius)
            {
                move = true;

                lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (lastRadius != radius)
            {
                move = true;

                lastRadius = radius;
            }
        }

        if (move)
        {
            if (transform.localPosition != radiusPosition)
            {
                float step = movingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition,
                    radiusPosition, step);
            }
            else
            {
                move = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now it's rotatearound on the xRadius only so if xRadius is set to 5 it will rotate around the Cube in radius 5 and iof i change to 1 so around the Cube at radius 1.

but i want to make that if both xRadius and yRadius are the same value like 5 then rotate around at radius 5 but if xRadius value is 5 and yRadius value 11 then it's drawing ellipse and i want the object to rotate around on the ellipse radius. not sure how to make it to rotate on ellipse in case xRadius and yRadius have different values ?

Answer (score 0):

`Transform.RotateAround` doesn’t support elliptical orbits. If you just want to move something in an elliptical orbit, I’d suggest doing it yourself using sine and cosine, e.g.:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundEliptical : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float radiusX, radiusY;
    public float speed;
    public float currentAngleInRadians;

    void Update()
    {
        currentAngleInRadians += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(
                Mathf.Cos(currentAngleInRadians) * radiusX,
                Mathf.Sin(currentAngleInRadians) * radiusY,
                0);
    }
}
```

If you put the object using this script inside a parent GameObject, you can move and rotate that parent GameObject to change the centre and the axis of the orbit. Make speed negative for clockwise rotation.